# Xpath Query Help. Selecting data from multiple paths as a single data set

Tags: xpath

I have an xml structure like the following :

```
<doc>
 <line void="false">
  <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
  <info1>ddddd</info1>
  <info2>aaaaa</info2>
 </line>

 <line void="true">
  <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
  <voidLineNumber>1</voidLineNumber>
  <voidValue>2.00</voidValue>
 </line>

</doc>
```

I need one single set of data. I would like to select all the lines where void = false as well as the voidLineNumber and voidValue data from the line where void = true and the voidLineNumber = lineNumber from the original line.

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand. Please show the expected output.

Comment: <line void="false>
<lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
<info1></info1>
<info2></info2>
<voidValue></voidValue>
</line>

Comment: XPath selects node lists, it cannot create entirely new structures of nodes.

Comment: If you want to create a new XML structure, use XSLT or XQuery. XPath can only select nodes from the input document, it cannot change them.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay noted, XPath itself can only be used to select nodes, not to transform them.  You can do what you want with XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="line" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="line">
    <xsl:variable name="voidvalue"><xsl:value-of select="@void" /></xsl:variable>

         <xsl:if test="$voidvalue='false'">
                 <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
                    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                             <xsl:if test="name(.)='lineNumber'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                             </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```